# C++:storing constant multi dimensional arrays in a pointer

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a project of which I should store constant multi dimensional arrays.I would like to do it with a pointer which points to multi-dimensional arrays.However, I could'nt succeeded.I write this code but it didn't compiled.

```
int darray[1][2];
    int darray2[2][3];
    int (*p)[1][2];
    p= new int[2];
    p[0] = darray;
    p[1] = darray2;
```

Comment: I would recommend making a `struct` for the constant multi dimensional arrays and then making a pointer for that `struct`

Comment: It's not clear what you want this code to do.  Do you want `p` to point at `darray`?  What is the purpose of `darray2`?

Comment: sorry it was darray2 which is stored at p[1]

Comment: @user1305058: Then this is really not clear.  `darray` and `darray2` are of different types (because they're different sizes).  This can never work, because the compiler won't know how to generate the correct pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth so you mean that I couldn't point to multi-dimensional array each of which has different sizes.

Comment: @user1305058: Not in a way that doesn't involve lots of ugly fiddling about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's go through your code line by line (OK, I'll lump the first two lines together)

```
int darray[1][2];
int darray2[2][3];
```

OK, this defines two two-dimensional arrays in exactly the way you (probably) expect. Note that formally, those are actually arrays of arrays of ints. More exactly, `darray` is of type "array of 1 array of 2 ints each", and darray2 is of type "array of 2 arrays of 3 ints each"

```
int (*p)[1][2];
```

This defines a pointer to a two-dimensional array of int, or to the first element of an array of such arrays. That is, the type of `p` is "pointer to array of 1 array of 2 ints each".

```
p= new int[2];
```

Here you are allocating space for two ints (i.e. an one-dimensional array of ints, of length two), and `new` returns a pointer to the *first element* of that array, i.e. a pointer to int. You try to assign that pointer to int to `p`, which is a pointer to array of 1 array of 2 ints each, as mentioned above. This gives a type mismatch and should not compile.

It's not entirely clear what you want at that point, but given that you do assignments to `p[0]` and `p[1]` afterward, and given that the return value is assigned to `p` which is of type `int (*)[1][2]` the obvious choice would be `p = new int[2][1][2];`

```
p[0] = darray;
```

This again doesn't work, because arrays in C++ are not first-class objects. That is, instead of assigning the value of `darray` to `p[0]` as the line would suggest (and `p[0]` indeed would have the right type for that) the rules of C++ say that the array `darray` is *promoted* to a *pointer to its first element*. That is, what this code *actually* tries to do is to assign a pointer to the first element of `darray` (of type `int (*)[2]`) to `p[0]` (of type `int[1][2]`), which of course fails. In C++, arrays are simply not assignable.

```
p[1] = darray2;
```

This suffers from the same problem, however note that even if arrays were first-class, assignable objects in C++, this still would be a type mismatch because `p[1]` is of type `int[1][2]` while `darray2` is of type `int[2][3]`.

Note that you get around most of those limitations (apart from the last one) by just wrapping you array into a class C++11 actually provides a standard class template called `std::array` for this purpose):

```
struct array12 { int data[1][2]; };
array12 darray;
array12* p;
p = new array12[2];
p[0] = darray;
```

With a bit more of programming you could also handle the assignment from larger to smaller arrays (your `darray2` case) by copying only part of the data by hand.